# How to translate "Fill" (in a form)

Tags: translation, word-requests

Say I have a form with differents fields to fill. How do I translate to japanese the word "Fill" (For example I have a button that when pressed will fill all the fields automatically)

Comment: I am voting to leave this question open, as I consider it a word-request, not specifically a request for translation.

Comment: If I were you, I would edit the post to make it more clear that you are referring to a form of some web application, and add that you are interested to know how to express the concept of "automatic filling". In this way it makes it even more clear that it is not just a request for translation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's the caption of a button, something like 自動入力 should be used. The closest single-word verb is [埋める](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%9F%8B%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B) (e.g., 空欄を埋める), but it's not a very natural choice when it comes to the auto-filling/autocomplete functionality on computer screen.

Comment: How about 記入? Would 自動記入 sound good?

Comment: 自動記入 is a valid option, but I think it's less common.